# ExtJS remoteFilter with List does not work

Tags: extjs6

I have a store with `remoteFilter: true` and I am getting the correct response back from my remote source when I load results and sort, but when I try and filter on a value I get the error in the console that says

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null`

I can see in my response from the server that the filtering is sending and receiving correctly.

In my grid column, I have the following (fake values - i'm typing them by hand because my code is on an intranet):

`{
    text: 'Header Whatever',
    dataIndex: 'status',
    filter: {
        type: 'list',
        dataIndex: 'remoteStatus',//the value from the remote source is different from my model (changing it doesn't fix it)
        single: true,
        options: [ 'visible', 'invisible' ]
    }
}`

Filtering on text strings in other columns works fine and if there are no results, I do not get an error. Filtering on my custom options calls to and gets the proper responses from the remote source, but I get the error and the loading mask doesn't go away.

All remote sorting works and filtering using strings works. Unfortunately, I have to supply a list of values for the user to filter with, so using string filters here is out of the question.

Any ideas what I'm missing? I'm using ExtJS 6.0.1. I've posted this issue in Sencha's forums, but there is not much support there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... I think the issue might have been with the loading of the list store. I was defining a new list store, but I guess it wasn't be instantiated. By adding the store by variable, I'm able to make it load

```
var mystore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id'],
    data: [
        { id: 'invisible'},
        { id: 'visible'}
    ]
});

....

filter: {
    type: 'list',
    store: mystore,
    idField: 'id',
    labelField: 'id',
    dataIndex: 'remoteStatus',
    ....
```